# Trouble with Scala pattern matching with map - required String

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to make my RDD into a pairdRDD, but having trouble with the pattern matching and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong..

```
val test = sc.textFile("neighborhood_test.csv");
val nhead0 = test.first;

val test_split = test.map(line => line.split("\t"));
val nhead = test_split.first;

val test_neigh0 = test.filter(line => line!= nhead0);
//test_neigh0.first = 3335  Dunlap  Seattle
val test_neigh1 = test_neigh0.map(line => line.split("\t")); 
//test_neigh1.first = Array[String] = Array(3335, Dunlap, Seattle)
val test_neigh = test_neigh1.map({case (id, neigh, city) => (id, (neigh, city))});
```

Gives error:

```
found   : (T1, T2, T3)
required: String
val test_neigh = test_neigh0.map({case (id, neigh, city) => (id, (neigh, city))});
```

**EDIT:**
The inputfile is tab seperated and looks like this:

```
id  neighbourhood   city
3335    Dunlap  Seattle
4291    Roosevelt   Seattle
5682    South Delridge  Seattle
```

As output I wan't a pairRDD with `id` as key, and `(neigh, city)` as value.

Comment: can you share some sample data and what is your expected output???

Comment: added some sample data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val baseRDD = sc.textFile("neighborhood_test.csv").filter { x => !x.contains("city") }
baseRDD.map { x =>
      val split = x.split("\t")
      (split(0), (split(1), split(2)))
    }.groupByKey().foreach(println(_))
```

**Result:**

(3335,CompactBuffer((Dunlap,Seattle)))

(4291,CompactBuffer((Roosevelt,Seattle)))

(5682,CompactBuffer((South Delridge,Seattle)))

Answer (score 3):

Neither `test_neigh0.first` nor `test_neigh1.first` is a triple, so you cannot pattern match it as such.

The elements in `test_neigh1` are `Array[String]`. Under the assumption that these arrays are all of length 3, you can pattern match against them as `{ case Array(id, neigh, city) => ...}`.

To make sure that you won't get a matching error if one of the line as more or less than 3 elements, you may collect on this pattern matching, instead of mapping on it.

```
val test_neigh: RDD[(String, (String, String))] = test_neigh1.collect{
  case Array(id, neigh, city) => (id, (neigh, city))
}
```

**EDIT**

The issues you experienced as described in your comment are related to `RDD[_]` not being a usual collection (such as `List`, `Array` or `Set`). To avoid those, you might need to fetch elements in the array without pattern matching:

```
val test_neigh: RDD[(String, (String, String))] = test_neigh0.map(line => {
  val arr = line.split("\t")
  (arr(0), (arr(1), arr(2))
})
```

Comment: Already tried the pattern match with Array(id,neigh,city) but I get an error: scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
 found   : Array[T]
 required: String.

Also tried the second suggestion but I get an error saying error: not found: type RDD

Comment: Are you sure you tried `map` and `collect` on `test_neigh1` and not `test_neigh0`? Your first issue seems to come from this. For your second issue, I assumed you were dealing with `RDD`s, but if it is not the case, please replace by the collection type you're using (or better yet, leave the compiler decide what it should be).

Comment: I've tried mapping on both `test_neigh1` and `test_neigh0`, just trying to get some results.. The solution in the EDIT also gave the error `not found: type RDD`. Both `test_neigh1` and `test_neigh0` are RDDs